# Is there any solution for modified t-test in python for spatial data?

Tags: python, statistics, correlation

I am searching for a solution to conduct a modified t-test or any other possibility in order to compute significant or non-significant relations in a spatial dataset (which can be a stack of rasters or a larger list of (irr-)regular points with several attached attributes).

The problem of faulty t-test is for example described in 
Dutilleul, P. 1993a. Modifying the t test for assessing the correlation between two spatial processes. Biometrics 49:305-314.

The only thing I found is [a solution in R.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SpatialPack/versions/0.3-8/topics/modified.ttest)

The test was implemented in the [software PASSAGE](http://www.passagesoftware.net/download2linuxcmd.php), which is not available anymore.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following which is a port of the implementation from R's SpatialPack:
https://github.com/sadaszewski/modified-ttest